# Select data from my three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables, one named `album`, while the other one is `soundtrack` and last but definitely not the least, is the `artist`.

Under one album is more than one track (obviously) and an artist name...

So this is how it should look like:

**Desired Output:**

```
 |---------------------|
 |AlbumName by Charlie |
 |---------------------|
 | 1. See you again    |
 |---------------------|
 | 2. One call Away    |
 |---------------------|
 | Album by Ed Sheeran |
 |---------------------|
 | 1. Perfect          |
 |---------------------|
 | 2. Dive             |
 |---------------------|
```

And below is `mysqli_fetch_array()` that I used along side with `while-loop` to populate the `<table>` tag.

```
$query = "SELECT a.* AS Album, b.* AS Track, c.* AS Artist 
        FROM album a 
        INNER JOIN track b ON a.album_id=b.album_id 
        INNER JOIN artist c ON a.artist_id=c.artist_id 
        ORDER BY a.album_id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$c=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $album = $row['Album']." (".$row['Artist'].") ";
   $track = $row['Track'];
}
```

The problem is, when I ran this code... I could only get this result...

```
|---------------------|
|AlbumName by Charlie |
|---------------------|
|  1. See you again   |
|---------------------|
|  2. One call away   |
|---------------------|
|  1. Perfect         |
|---------------------|
|  2.  Dive           |
|---------------------|
```

It got the list of the soundtracks, including the soundtrack's ID right, however, things didn't do well on the `Album Name`

I want it just to look like the **Desired Output**. Any ideas? I've tried to search stackoverflow, but it seems it couldn't direct me on the same question, so I made my own. Please forgive (do not flag) me if it had an existing already, its just that I didn't know where to find it. And pleeeeease... I need an immediate and working answer. Thanks guys!

As for DATABASE Structure

```
album = {album_id, artist_id,album_title}
artist = {artist_id, artist_name}
track = {song_id, album_id, song_title}
```

**UPDATE!** 
Okay, so this goes a little bit out of control. When I tried @swellar's suggestion this what happened. And when I undo it, the output remains the same.
See the result below...

```
|---------------------|
|AlbumName by Charlie |
|---------------------|
|  1. See you again   |
|---------------------|
|AlbumName by Charlie |
|---------------------|
|  2. One Call Away   |
|---------------------|
|AlbumName by Charlie |
|---------------------|
|  1.  Perfect        |
|---------------------|
|AlbumName by Charlie |
|---------------------|
|  2.   Dive          |
|---------------------|
```

What I want is to give each `Album` one or more than soundtrack but it get so messed up each time I dare to change the `query`. How can I sanitize the `mysqli_fetch_array()` for it to display the desired output?

Comment: Just an alternative, why not do two queries? One for getting the `album` and the `artist`, while the other one is for getting the soundtracks. While the first query loops, run the next query where you will use the `album_id`/`artist_id` or whatever the foreign key is, to get all the soundtracks needed

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit, but the code doesn't actually create any output.

Comment: How does your database look exactly?

Comment: Also, how exactly are you printing it out? Where are the actual echoes?

Comment: Please, if you can, provide a screenshot of your database scheme.

Comment: @Swellar I just tried it, but to no avail. It keeps on looping Charlie's name in every song, even to Ed Sheeran's.

`<br>
|AlbumName by Charlie |
<br>
|  1. See you again   |<br>
|AlbumName by Charlie |
<br>
|  2. One call away   |<br>
|AlbumName by Charlie |<br>
|  1. Perfect         |<br>
|AlbumName by Charlie |
<br>
|  2.  Dive           |<br>
|AlbumName by Charlie |<br>

<br> I've tried using LIMIT by it only shows `Album by Charilie` and `See you again`... any suggestion?

Comment: Can you also include your database? What I'm expecting is even without the `soundtrack` query, you will only receive two data. How exactly did you do the `album`/`artist` query?

Comment: I put `INNER JOIN` when I query the `album` and the `artist` table. But only does a simple `select * from track` with `where` clause ofcourse.

Comment: I think you use something like `SELECT album.*, artist.* FROM album INNER JOIN artist.artistid ON album.artistid`. You are only getting the album and artist, so why would you still query from the `track` table?

Comment: @ezw, I've use <table> tag to achieve the desire output, by calling the <?php echo $album; ?> and <?php echo $track; ?> on a <td> attribute. I choose not to put all of my codes, because I got too sensitive when it comes to it. Sorry. But, I guess you all get my point right? I mean calling an echo inside <table> isn't a new thing.

Comment: I've never seen `table.* AS alias` before. Aliases can only be assigned to specific columns, it doesn't make sense to assign it to `*`.

Answer (score -3):

Here is your SQL

Notice I've put 3 order by in there. First by the artist name, which would keep all artist's stuff grouped together, then by album name and then by song id.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.album_title AS Album,
               t.song_title AS Track,
               t.song_id AS ID,
               n.artist_name AS Artist
        FROM album AS a
            INNER JOIN track AS t
                ON a.album_id = t.album_id
            INNER JOIN artist AS n
                ON a.artist_id = n.artist_ID
        ORDER BY n.artist_name ASC,
                 a.album_id ASC,
                 t.song_id ASC";


/*
That SQL will generate the following array

Array
(
    [Album] => AlbumName
    [Track] => See you again
    [ID] => 1
    [Artist] => Charlie
)
Array
(
    [Album] => AlbumName
    [Track] => One call Away
    [ID] => 2
    [Artist] => Charlie
)
Array
(
    [Album] => Album
    [Track] => Perfect
    [ID] => 1
    [Artist] => Ed Sheeran
)
Array
(
    [Album] => Album
    [Track] => Dive
    [ID] => 2
    [Artist] => Ed Sheeran
)
*/
```

Below is your while loop

```
<table>
<?php
// Some placeholders
$album = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['Album'] !== $album)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #dedede;"><?php echo $row['Album']; ?> by <?php echo $row['Artist']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?>: <?php echo $row['Track']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?>: <?php echo $row['Track']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }

   $album = $row['Album'];
}
?>
</table>
```

Overall Output is:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #dedede;">AlbumName by Charlie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;">1: See you again</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;">2: One call Away</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #dedede;">Album by Ed Sheeran</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;">1: Perfect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;">2: Dive</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are better ways to go around doing this, but not knowing your work environment, skills, requirements, other code, w/e this is the best quick and dirty solution for you to base your solution of. This works to what you requested.

Comment: Err.. I had an existing code which is pretty much the same as your's, but not exactly. coz as you can see at my sample code I used iteration for it. If you saw the `$i=0` at the top of my sample, that's what am referring to.

However, it doesn't show each `Album Name` separately. Like, Charlie's Album Name keep popping even to Ed's track. I've used `LIMIT` but it completely ignores Ed's Album name

Comment: the problem is not on the declaration of `<table>` tag. Because you'll just simply call on the `<td><?php echo $var ?></td>` But my case is quite different because I want it to display just as the Desired Output. However, it keeps on repeating Album_Name by Charlie

Please read my whole post. The reason why your code is working is because its not calling the values from the `DB` when I press the run code snippet. It calls the values you've declared on the <table>